# Restriction of an everywhere continuous to open, closed and bounded subsets and uniform continuity.

Tags: continuity, uniform-continuity

Let $f : \Bbb R \longrightarrow \Bbb R$ be an arbitrary everywhere continuous function. Let $I \subseteq \Bbb R$ be an interval.  What can we say about the uniform continuity of $f$ on $I$ where $I$ is respectively open, closed and bounded?

For open and bounded cases I can restrict the everywhere continuous function $f(x) = x^2$ on $(0,1).$ Then $f$ is not uniformly continuous.

Now what can I do for closed intervals? Can I get the same kind of counter-examples? If that closed set is bounded then it is compact  and we know that any continuous function on a compact set is uniformly continuous. So if we want to get a counter-example we need to work with closed and unbounded sets one of which is $\Bbb R$ itself and the same function $f(x)=  x^2$ will work for this case also. So we are done with all the cases.

Is my reasoning correct at all? Someone please verify it.

Thank you very much.

Comment: What do you mean by your second paragraph? The function $f : (0, 1) \to \Bbb{R} : x \mapsto x^2$ **is** uniformly continuous.

Comment: Yeah now I realise. I cannot take $f(x)= x^2$ on $(0,1).$ What I can take instead?

Comment: If $f: \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ is everywhere continuous, and $I$ is any bounded subset of $\Bbb{R}$ (doesn't matter open/closed/ mixed/disconnected whatever) then $f$ restricted to $I$ is uniformly continuous, because $I$ (by virtue of being bounded) lies inside some compact (closed and bounded) interval $[-R,R]$, and $f$ restricted to $[-R,R]$ is uniformly continuous (it's a standard theorem that continuous functions on compact sets are uniformly continuous) and hence restricted to $I$ is also uniformly continuous

Comment: Take $1/x$ instead.